# advanced search with multiple query in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, backend, advanced-search

i have collection of 10 data collections like below

```
{
"name":"peter",
"movie":"spider3",
"rating":10,
"genres":["thriller","mystery"]     }
```

the movie controller with aggregation is

```
export const getMovies = async (req, res) => {
//const genre="romance"
const genre = req.query.genre
const movies = await Movie.aggregate(
    [

        { $unwind: "$genres" },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$genres',
                movieCount: { $sum: 1 },
                movies: {
                    $push: "$movie"
                }
            }
        },
        {$addFields:{genre:'$_id'}},
        {$project:{_id:0}},
        { $match: { genre: genre } }
    ]
)
res.status(200).json({ movies })    }
```

so with this I could find movies with genre. But I also need to search with rating and actor name. how to achieve it with aggregation.

my search query would be

**http://localhost:4000/api/getmovie?genre=action&rating=8&name=peter**

Comment: Not sure what is your expected format of output. But if you just want to do the filtering it could be simple as [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZwsSlH2eLWu)